# When to use parametric/GLM/ANOVA, in relation to data normality

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, normality-assumption

In my experiment we looked at colour change (luminance) following a predatory stimulus (presence and lock of being the two treatments). The data consists of luminance before, after and the % change between. Data is independent with 23 individuals for each treatment.

I want to examine if treatment had an effect on the change. **I was under the impression that parametric tests can only be used when the data has a normal distribution. however I have recently seen that my uni notes says for GLM, only the residuals have to be normal.** Is this correct? does it differ between parametric tests that aren't fitting a model? (Fitting lm(%change~treatment), with the %change square rooted fits the residual assumptions)

Moreover, **is this the best way to analyse the data? I.e., should I compare before and after based on treatment or just change? and should this be absolute or relative?** I also want to look at whether the starting value had an impact on the effect of treatment - would this best be done in a separate analysis, e.g., correlation, or should I fit a model including both variables?

Comment: "recently seen that my uni notes says for GLM, only the residuals have to be normal" -- If that's what your notes say, then your notes are wrong. Generalized linear models assume some member of the exponential dispersion family of distributions; most of those will not have normal distributions for residuals (i.e. $y_i - \hat{y}_i$); indeed since they will typically have different variances and in some cases different distribution shapes for every observation, the residuals may not be at all normal-looking when the model is correct.

Comment: e.g. try simulating from a simple intercept-only Bernoulli model (since you're simulating you know the assumed model is correct) and see how the distribution of residuals looks. Alternatively try a two-group model, with distinct values for $p$

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! A note on terminology: "GLM" can stand for "generalized linear model" (most common use on this site, I think) or "general linear model"; the distinction is explained on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/generalized-linear-model/info). A "generalized linear model" allows for parametric models when error terms are other than normally distributed. I think you meant "general linear model" in this question. "Multiple linear regression" is less potentially confusing than using "GLM" for "general linear model."

Comment: @EdM I agree with you that OP is almost certainly asking about normal linear models. I suspect the question relates to the common misunderstanding about the dependent variable being normally distributed with means specified by the linear model vs the dependent variable being normal iid. As you would know, many learners assume that "normal" means iid, i.e., they assume that a normally distributed dependent variable must look normal on an histogram.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend that you *don't* evaluate `%_change` as the outcome variable. See [this post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/) for why that type of value can be confusing. It's best to work with data closest to the original observations, here the `before` and `after` values.

Second, a standard linear regression model assumes that the error distribution is *independent of* the true value. Data of this type often have errors more or less *proportional to* the true value. If that's the case here, with luminance (`lum`) values all greater than 0 and only 2 observations per individual (one before and one after the stimulus), you can consider working with log-transformed `lum` values.

I'll illustrate suggestions with log-transformed values, although you could do the following with non-transformed values or with any monotonic transformation that your understanding of the subject matter might suggest.

For example, the following model (in R):

```
lm(I(log(lum_after) - log(lum_before)) ~ treatment)
```

can be considered a paired *t*-test (within individuals) on the log-transformed values, or equivalently an evaluation of the effect of `treatment` on the log of the `after/before` ratio, as $\log A - \log B =\log (A/B)$.

An alternative, providing more flexibility in the association between `lum_before` and `lum_after` values, could be to use `lum_before` along with `treatment` as a predictor, for example:

```
lm(log(lum_after) ~ log(lum_before) + treatment).
```

That model, however, assumes that the association of `treatment` with `log(lum_after)` is independent of `log(lum_before)`.

> I also want to look at whether the starting value had an impact on the effect of treatment.

For that it's best to use a single, slightly more complicated model rather than the ones suggested above. To evaluate whether the association of one predictor with outcome depends on the value of another predictor, you need to include an interaction term, usually written in R as:

```
lm(log(lum_after) ~ log(lum_before) * treatment),
```

which is equivalent to

```
lm(log(lum_after) ~ log(lum_before) + treatment + log(lum_before):treatment).
```

The `:` indicates the interaction term. You have to be very careful interpreting the coefficients of a model with an interaction, however.

The intercept will be the estimated value of `log(lum_after)` when `log(lum_before)=0` and `treatment` is at its reference level. The coefficient for `log(lum_before)` will be its estimated further linear association with `log(lum_after)` *when* `treatment` *is at its reference level*. The coefficient for `treatment` will be the estimated *difference* in `log(lum_after)` when `treatment` isn't at the reference level *and when* `log(lum_before)=0`. The coefficient for the interaction term is the estimated *extra difference* from what you would predict based solely on the intercept and the individual coefficients for `log(lum_before)` and `treatment`.

In the context of the above "general" (versus "generalized") linear models, your old course notes are sort of correct but might be a bit too stringent. [Homoscedastic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/heteroscedasticity/info) normally distributed residuals (in the transformed scale, if any), as in your course notes, certainly simplify things. The requirement for normality can be relaxed, however, if the data set is large enough that the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) holds for the coefficient estimates. [Heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroskedasticity-consistent_standard_errors) can help deal with lack of homoscedasticity.

Finally, as "GLM" more typically refers to "generalized linear model" than to the "general linear models" noted above, I'll point out that there is a type of "generalized linear model" that might also be used here. The above models on log-transformed values evaluate effects in terms of the means of the log-transformed values. It's also possible to evaluate effects on the logs of the mean values rather than on the means of the logs, with the following GLM:

```
glm(lum_after ~ lum_before + treatment + lum_before:treatment, family= gaussian(link = "log").
```

See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/525590/28500) for the difference between the two approaches. I typically find that working with logs directly is adequate and easier to explain to other biologists.